# DC Circuit Analysis from Sergio Franco Book : Electric Circuit Fundamentals

Tags: dc, kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law, circuits, nodal-analysis

[image]

[image]

If current source is absorbing power then the polarity wise Vb will be +ve.Then i calculated the value of Vb=4 x 2A = 8V
Va= Vb + (20*2) = 48V
and Vs = 164V
Thus for current source to absorb power of 0 W., voltage source has to change from 17V to 164 V. But ansewr is 140V. Even if i take
Change = 164-17V = 147V. 
Where am i wrong ?

Comment: Well, I reckon the answer is minus 24 volts (for what it's worth). This is based on the current i2 being zero amps. Maybe I'm misreading it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that to get power equal to \$P = 0W\$ for a current source. We need to have \$P = 2A * v_B = 0W\$
Therefore \$v_B = 0V\$ becouse now \$P = 2A * 0V = 0W\$.

This also implies that \$I_1 = 0A \$ and \$I_2 = 2A\$.

Now it should be easy to see why the answer is \$v_S = 140V\$

Comment: Makes complete sense +1